# How would I include 5k+ unstaged changes into .gitignore file?

Tags: git, git-bash

Shot in the dark here:  I have returned to vs code after stepping away for quite awhile and I see that each time I open a new file I soon have over 5,000 unstaged changes.  I imagine these must be untracked from a previous project? I am a total newbie to git but am not attached to many files on my machine and am open to beginner friendly solutions / broad sweeping deletions if necessary. Any guidance is very appreciated.

Comment: You can include a directory name/path in .gitignore, to exclude the whole thing

Comment: @l0b0 we can also use regex here to exclude certain types of files here.

Comment: When you look at the diff, what are those unstaged changes? (I would guess a line ending issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doiuble-check first where is your Git repository, meaning where do you find a `.git` subfolder where you open a new file.

Is it in the folder of the file you are opening or in one of the parent folder?

The point is: I have seen repositories created by mistake in the home folder, thereby considering *all* files of the user HOME as being potentially trackable.
Those would be listed as "Untracked" (not staged), which the OP might have described as "unstaged".

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I was actually able to locate the file and establish a direct path for my gitignore file and that resolved the issue.